# Applying the theorem of Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I have to fund the extremas of $f$ subject to the contraints, that are given:

$$fx, y)=x-y, x^2-y^2=2$$

I have done the following:

We use the theorem of Lagrange multipliers.

The constraint is $g(x,y)=x^2-y^2-2=0$.

We have to find $x$, $y$ and $\lambda$ such that $$\nabla f(x,y)=\lambda \nabla g(x, y) \tag 1$$ and $$g(x,y)=0 \tag 2$$

$$\nabla f(x,y)=(1, -2) \ \ , \ \ \nabla g(x, y)=(2x, -2y)$$

$$(1) \Rightarrow (1, -1)=\lambda (2x, -2y) \Rightarrow x=y$$

$$(2) \Rightarrow x^2-y^2=2 \Rightarrow x^2-x^2=2 \Rightarrow 0=2$$

What have I done wrong??

Comment: Weird. I did the calculations using a determinant instead of $\nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y)$ and I also got $0=2$.

Comment: no extrema exist

Comment: The argument is correct. Since Lagrange's theorem gives a necessary condition for the extrema of a function to exist, and since we arrive at a contradiction, so we conclude that no extrema can exist.

Comment: Makes sense. The hyperbola there is not compact, there is no reason why we necessarily should have an extremum there.

Comment: So, is Lagrange multipliers method an "if and only if" statement?? @Chou

Comment: No :) It only narrows down the possibilities. One still has to find the extrema geometrically or analytically.

Comment: As **Ivo Terek** points out, the constraint curve is a hyperbola; it is in fact a "horizontal" hyperbola, with its focal axis on the $ \ x-$ axis, centered on the origin.  Its asymptotes are thus $ \ y \ = \ \pm x \ $ .  The "level curves" of the function are thus _parallel_ to one of the asymptotes, so there is _no possibility_ of the Lagrange-multiplier method finding a tangent point to the hyperbola on any of the level curves.  Since the hyperbola is infinite in extent, there will be no global extrema for the function.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already noticed, if $(x, y) \in g^{(-1)}\{ 0 \}$ such that $f$ has an extremum at $(x, y)$, then, since $\lambda = 0$ is easily seen to lead to a contradiction, we have $x = y.$ However, since $(x, y) \in g^{(-1)}\{ 0 \},$ we have $x^{2} - y^{2} = 2,$ which implies that $x \neq y.$

Therefore, $f$ restricted on $g^{(-1)}\{ 0 \}$ has no extremum.